# NUM_NULLS and NUM_ROWS not work for Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find the number of total rows, and the number of null rows for each column in a database. I feel like the following should work, but each time I run it the `num_nulls` and `num_rows` came back blank (So I put in the `COALESCE` so it now results in a 0)

> SELECT atc.column_name, atc.table_name, atc.data_type, COALESCE(atc.num_nulls, 0),  COALESCE(at.num_rows, 0)
>   FROM
>       all_tab_columns atc JOIN all_tables at ON ATC.TABLE_NAME = at.table_name ;

Is there something wrong with my code or is it possible the `all_tab_columns` or `all_tables` are not up to date?

PS. The tables do have information in them, I have already checked to see if the database was empty.

Comment: Have you re-gathered the table stats? `exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user,'TABLE_NAME')`

Comment: Even if the stats are gathered and are reasonably up-to-date they won't be an accurate count of the contents. It might be good enough to give a rough approximation of the proportion of empty/populated columns but shouldn't really be relied on for anything beyond that.

Comment: @paul I haven't, but when I tried that it says I don't have the right privileges to do it.

Comment: @AlexPoole, Do you know of a better way to get accurate information?

Comment: How accurate do you need it to be, and why? The only way to get accurate information is to count the actual data in the tables - but you still only know what the count was at that moment in time. In 11g the numbers can be accurate at the moment the stats are gathered but are likely to be stale by the time you look at them. You probably need to look at why you need the numbers and what they'll be used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the all_tab_columns table to generate a script for you that looks something like this:

```
with data as (
    select
        count(*) tot_rows,
        count(owner) owner,
        count(object_name) object_name,
        count(subobject_name) subobject_name
    from tblname
)
select column_name, not_null_count, tot_rows - not_null_count null_count
from data
unpivot (
    not_null_count
    for column_name in (owner,object_name,subobject_name)
);
```

Which will give you the results:

```
COLUMN_NAME    NOT_NULL_COUNT NULL_COUNT
-------------- -------------- ----------
OWNER                     801          0
OBJECT_NAME               801          0
SUBOBJECT_NAME              0        801
```